# Android studio, XML Inflation error on main activity creation android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Hours have gone by and i still can't get round this really frustrating error.
i'm new to android programming so i'm pretty much following tutorials and trying to understand them as i move along. i've also tryed different approaches but keep getting the same error.

```
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testapp.scott.mpt/com.testapp.scott.mpt.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class fragment
```

Here's my Fragment Layout (I'm using a shape as a background button. that's not the problem because i've tryed removing it and nothing changed...)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.testapp.scott.mpt.MainToolbarFrag"
    android:background="#ff434343">


<Button
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="My desk"
    android:id="@+id/BT_Toolbar_MyDesk"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_buttonbk"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Exercises"
    android:id="@+id/BT_Toolbar_Exercises"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_buttonbk"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="My\nProfile"
    android:id="@+id/BT_Toolbar_MyProfile"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_buttonbk"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Extras"
    android:id="@+id/BT_Toolbar_Extras"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_buttonbk"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity in which i would want the fragment to be displayed:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >


<Space
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:id="@+id/Space0" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/main_welcome"
    android:id="@+id/TV_Main_Welcome"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:password="false"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="74dp"
    class="com.testapp.scott.mpt.MainToolbarFrag"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_row="30"
    android:layout_column="0"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_maintoolbar" />
```

My Fragment Java Class:

```
package com.testapp.scott.mpt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link MainToolbarFrag.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link MainToolbarFrag#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 *
 */

public class MainToolbarFrag extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment MainToolbarFrag.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MainToolbarFrag newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MainToolbarFrag fragment = new MainToolbarFrag();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    public MainToolbarFrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maintoolbar, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

And my main Activity class:

```
package com.testapp.scott.mpt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.testapp.scott.mpt.MyClasses.Constants;
import com.testapp.scott.mpt.MyClasses.Exercises;
import com.testapp.scott.mpt.MyClasses.UserData;
import com.testapp.scott.mpt.MyClasses.deskData;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.ParseException;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();


        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

And FInally this is my Log:

```
10-13 20:51:54.974    1678-1678/com.testapp.scott.mpt D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-13 20:51:54.994    1678-1684/com.testapp.scott.mpt D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-13 20:51:55.074    1678-1678/com.testapp.scott.mpt D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-13 20:51:55.074    1678-1678/com.testapp.scott.mpt W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41941d88)
10-13 20:51:55.074    1678-1678/com.testapp.scott.mpt E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.testapp.scott.mpt, PID: 1678
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testapp.scott.mpt/com.testapp.scott.mpt.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:297)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.testapp.scott.mpt.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.testapp.scott.mpt.MyActivity@44aea5d0 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
            at com.testapp.scott.mpt.MainToolbarFrag.onAttach(MainToolbarFrag.java:84)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:853)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1146)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4786)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:297)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.testapp.scott.mpt.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've already fixed the missing implementation in my activity class.
The real problem here is the inflation error.
Thanks!

Comment: Try to class="com.testapp.scott.mpt.MainToolbarFrag" replace android:name="com.testapp.scott.mpt.MainToolbarFrag"

Answer (score 1):

your problem is from these lines of code:

```
   @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }
```

your activity must implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener`, but you do not implement that in your MyActivity.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no point in answering questions if the answer doesn't reply to the question asked (Please note the last two lines of my question)...
That being said, i figured out how to solve the problem and for anyone having the same issue the problem resided in the fact that MyActivity was not pointing to the fragment in it's onCreate() Method.

i solved it by changing

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();


    }
}
```

in particular the line:

```
.add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
```

to:

```
.add(R.id.container, new MainToolbarFrag())
```

where MainToolbarFrag() is the class of your fragment.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake because in your code you have not implemented that, anyway you could add comment to inform me about it.